# pointer function in C not working

Tags: c, function, pointers

I intend to make my pointer print the value, but it just stops working (no error report from the MinGW) . . .

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void point_here(int *yolo) {
      int you = 2014;
      yolo = &you;

    }


    main () {
      int *punk = NULL;

      point_here(punk);
      printf("Punk @ %d is not dead\w/.\n", *punk);

   }
```

How do I make this work? And why this does not work? Please explain. I'm new to pointers and C, and still confuse after reading stuff.

Answer (score 0):

C is "call by value"; functions get copies of the caller's values, not references to them. If you change an argument inside the function, nothing happens in the caller's context.

To work around this you need explicit pointers, but even you still can't have a pointer to a local variable inside a function persist beyond the running of that function.

Comment: _but even you still can't have a pointer to a local variable inside a function persist beyond the running of that function._ Sir pardon?

Comment: @user3203014 he means the variable `you` is basically gone after `point_here` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `NULL` as an argument to a function which effectively doesn't nothing. Then you try to dereference that NULL pointer which is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

This modified version of your code works well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void point_here(int *yolo) {
  *yolo = 2014;
}

int main () {
  int value = 0;
  int *punk = &value;
  point_here(punk);
  printf("Punk @ %d is not dead\w/.\n", *punk);
  return 0;
}
```

As others have said, you have the following issues:

- Pointer to a function value doesn't work after the function finishes executing
- You aren't passing the pointer to the pointer you are passing the pointer value. (In other words, you aren't editing what you think you are).

I fixed these two issues by passing in a pointer that has already been allocated, then you just modify it in the function. This is one standard way to use pointers. Best of luck!

Comment: Why do I have to allocate _*punk_ to _&value_ (which is 0) and not just directly allocate it to NULL?  
Then why change the parameter of _point_here_ to _*yolo_ (why remove the _*x_)?

Comment: You can allocate space a number of ways. The simplest way is to declare a variable and that allocates the memory for that variable. Thats what creating the "int value" does for you. Another way is using "malloc". This line of code looks like: `int *punk = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 problems. First the pointer variable is pass by value, second the variable "you" is on stack which gets lost once the function returns.

Change the variable you to static like

```
static int you = 2014;
```

and change the argument to **yolo;

Comment: Question 1: "First the pointer variable is pass by value..." 
Do you refer to the pointer "*yolo" or "*punk?" 

Question 2: And re: "**yolo" that's a double pointer, right? Why do I need to use a double pointer? Is it because I have already allocated the value of *yolo to "int you"?

Sorry I still don't quite get the explanations below.

Comment: Question 1:  the pointer variable punk is copied into a new variable which is yolo. Thats why punk is never changed in the function call. 
Question 2: double pointer means the pointer to pointer variable so the pointer variable is changed.